# CentOS 6.2 Jailing sftp account

Tags: ftp, centos, sftp

I have been tasked with setting up a centOS 6.2 development box (even though I do not know linux) and am currently using vsftpd to FTP into a box at work. The problem is sftp is not working.

> Authentication failed. Error: Critical error Error:   Could not connect
>   to server

this is the error I am getting.

I have added the user by doing the following:

```
sudo useradd -d /var/www/PATH -s /usr/sbin/nologin USERNAME
sudo passwd USERNAME

sudo chown -R USERNAME /var/www/ PATH 
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/PATH
```

it works for ftp (and the folder structure is jailed) but it does not work with sftp.

However, when I add a user the following way:

```
sudo useradd USERNAME
sudo passwd USERNAME
sudo chown –R USERNAME /opt/USERNAME
sudo chmod 777 /opt/USERNAME
```

I have sftp access unjailed and no FTP access.

It does not matter if I have to create multiple accounts (one for ftp and one for sftp), they do have to be jailed to the directory.

If there is a better solution to my problem, help would be welcomed!

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on good way.

Personally I am using chrooting of sftp user described here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/

IMHO in article is not stressed out enough that user's home directory has to be owned by root

```
    # ls -ld /var/www/PATH
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 28 23:49 /var/www/PATH
```

You can get a lot of helpful info from logs, it this case you can search

```
    tail -f /var/log/secure
```

while connecting from external host.

Let me know if you have any more help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a script for this purpose, you can use it what ever the distribution that you are using is, it works on both RHEL based and Deb's as well to create a jailed SFTP directory with no shell access, only SFTP.

[SFTP Jailing with no shell access](https://github.com/Laith-Alobaidy/-NIX/blob/master/SFTP%20Jailing)